# Name of a job for working in a workshop

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word indicating that I am interested in working in a workshop, meaning working with machines, wood carpentry, metal carpentry, even making automatons, and making stuff with hands. I am going to add this to the interests part of my C.V.

Comment: Are you trying to express your interest in that as opposed to working in an office?

Comment: Something like "industrial arts"?

Comment: You are covering quite a few different skills.  Machining metal parts, carpentry, and pottery are all different things.  I wouldn't look for one word to summarize.  I would list the specific things I was interested in, much as you already have done in your question.  There is a chance that a summarizing word may be incorrectly interpreted and skimmed over.

Answer (score 1):

Woodworking, whether by machine or by hand carving, metalworking whether by machining or welding are all [handiwork](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handiwork). As is knitting and sewing. People with such skills are called [craftsmen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craftsman). Or if you prefer; crafts*people*, and their ability is called **craftsmanship**.

Answer (score 0):

The word you need might be

[***manufacturing***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/manufacturing). The link is from dictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

Working with lathes and mills to cut and shape metal is called "machining."